# What is right way to prevent Blogspot blog's no country redirect?

Tags: blogger

Blogger uses country level domain e.g. same blog has different URL in different country e.g. if you open my blog http://java67.blogspot.com on India it will show http://java67.blogspot.in, but if you open it on UK it will show java67.blogspot.co.uk. I have read that you can prevent this redirect by adding /ncr (no country redirect) to URL e.g. java67.blogspot.com/ncr if opened in India will also show the same URL.

But current ways to use this require Javascript redirect, which looks spammy and also shows as self-referral in GA.

Do you guys suggest any legitimate and right way to prevent this re-direction?

Answer (score 4):

The only way is not to host your (sub)-domain on blogspot.com, but to use blogger with own hosted domain name. Country redirects are applied only to blogs which use blogspot.com domain infrastructure.

Register your own domain name and bind it to the blogger - blogger's backend has options for it.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of country-specific re-direct is so that if Google has to block your site in a country, it is only blocked in that country and not world-wide.   For that reason alone, it is best not to try finding a way around the re-directs.